# How to display UInt32[] into console in c#?

Tags: c#, blowfish

I want to implement algorithm blowfish for my work, i use source code blowfish c# from [defuse](https://defuse.ca/blowfish.htm), then i want to analysis the source code, then when i want to know output in some function i got message like this `System.UInt32[]` i want to display it to console.

This is part which i want to know the output.

```
int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        {
            uint d = (uint)(((key[j % cipherKey.Length] * 256 + key[(j + 1) % cipherKey.Length]) * 256 + key[(j + 2) % cipherKey.Length]) * 256 + key[(j + 3) % cipherKey.Length]);
            bf_P[i] ^= d;
            j = (j + 4) % cipherKey.Length; 
        }
        string p = Convert.ToString(bf_P);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+print+array shows you sample directly...

Answer (score 0):

```
string p = string.Join("\r\n", bf_P);
```

Comment: thanks it work for me?